# Join tables from firebase with React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-native-firebase

Hi I am new with React Native, I am making an app which manages societies, I have added "departments" and "societies" tables in my firebase database, now I want to join these tables in such a way that if I delete values from departments then also my respective society aganist it also deleted.

This is my delete department function, also Delete society fun is same;

```
deleteDept = () => {
  var abcd = deptref
    .orderByChild('uuid')

  abcd.once('value', function(abcdSnap) {
    var a = abcdSnap.val();
    var b = Object.keys(a)[0];

    deptref.child(b)
      .remove()
      .then(function() {
        console.log('Remove succeeded.');
        alert('Department Removed ');
        this.setState({
          isDialogVisible: false
        });
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log('Remove failed: ' + error.message);
      });
  });
};
```

[This is my firebase database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QgTv.png)

Comment: 2 things. 1. Always indent your code properly to ensure readability. 2. What database are you using? firebase realtime database or firestore?

Comment: firebase realtime, I've read we use ".once" in firebase to connect two tables but don't know how to use it plus in the picture link that I've attached with my code if department name and description matches from both tables then they both get deleted @Kiong

Answer (score 0):

You can't think of firebase realtime as you do for RDBMS / SQL databases. Think of firebase realtime as one big JSON object whereby to access the data you want, its through the object key (which is also  the URL). This means there is no such thing as "joins" in a JSON object (and firebase realtime). I'd suggest read up more on the best practices to design your schema. Yes, for firebase realtime, expect it to have duplicated data (unlike SQL dbs).

---

tl;dr:

1. Design your schema to be as flat as possible
2. Don't store your data as arrays. If you do, firebase will store the array as an object whose keys are the array's index:

   array = [
     'aha',
     'hoho'
   ]

will be stored as:

```
array: {
  0: 'aha',
  1: 'hoho'
}
```

3. Design your schema so that you can fetch the data you want in as little call as possible (yes, to do that, expect duplicated data):

For example:

```
{
  users: {
    user_id1: {
      name: 'user 1',
      phone: '123456',
      email: 'testt@gmail.com'
    }
  },
  events: {
    participantst: {
      user_id1: {   // <= note for here I only want user's name & email thus its in this manner
        name: 'user 1',
        email: 'test@gmail.com'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

NOT

```
{
  users: {
    user_id1: {
      name: 'user 1',
      phone: '123456',
      email: 'testt@gmail.com'
    }
  },
  events: {
    participantst: {
      user_id1: user_id1 // <= Doing it like this means you would need to make another call to the 'users' node to fetch the user data
    }
  }
}
```

and a lot more.

Comment: Thank You for this, it surely adds up in my knowledge, now can you tell me what should I do in my code so that if both of the field name matches in departments and societies tables then if I delete value from department then same value from society also deleted.

Comment: 2 choices: 1. manually trigger a delete on BOTH nodes. 2. Create a cloud function for firebase to listen for a delete on department node to then delete the same value from society node